# Cannot write csv file with python

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert json file into csv file. The json file came from tweepy.

```
import json
import csv

fo = open('Sclass.json', 'r')
fw = open('Hasil_Tweets.csv', 'a')

for line in fo:
        try:
                tweet = json.loads(line)
                fw.write(tweet['id'],tweet['timestamp_ms'],tweet['user']['name'],tweet['user']['statuses_count'],tweet['user']['friends_count'],tweet['user']['followers_count'],tweet['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates'],tweet['text']+"\n")
        except:
                continue
```

But when I print it, it works.
And when I write just `fw.write(tweet['text'])` it works.

I am a noob on either python and tweepy. But my instinct say, this problem is related to the json file itself.

This is the json file itself:

```
{
    "created_at": "Wed Oct 11 08:36:21 +0000 2017",
    "id": 918032510927355904,
    "id_str": "918032510927355904",
    "text": "@irfanzayo @puisisi @tasyak Lo tuh kebiasaan overthinking \ud83d\ude24",
    "display_text_range": [
        28,
        59
    ],
    "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": 918032029094047746,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "918032029094047746",
    "in_reply_to_user_id": 60049976,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "60049976",
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": "irfanzayo",
    "user": {
        "id": 59980455,
        "id_str": "59980455",
        "name": "Mutiara Sisyanni D",
        "screen_name": "MutiaraSisyanni",
        "location": "Jakarta, Indonesia",
        "url": "http://mutiarasyn.wixsite.com/mutiarasisyanni",
        "description": null,
        "translator_type": "none",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 354,
        "friends_count": 237,
        "listed_count": 1,
        "favourites_count": 326,
        "statuses_count": 6507,
        "created_at": "Sat Jul 25 04:31:47 +0000 2009",
        "utc_offset": 25200,
        "time_zone": "Jakarta",
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "FA8C9E",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme5/bg.gif",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme5/bg.gif",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_link_color": "FF8A94",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "99CC33",
        "profile_text_color": "3E4415",
        "profile_use_background_image": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/486497248293826560/FANdzhL9_normal.jpeg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/486497248293826560/FANdzhL9_normal.jpeg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/59980455/1404826066",
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": {
        "id": "66555622726ab358",
        "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/66555622726ab358.json",
        "place_type": "city",
        "name": "Setia Budi",
        "full_name": "Setia Budi, Indonesia",
        "country_code": "ID",
        "country": "Indonesia",
        "bounding_box": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [
                        106.817351,
                        -6.24152
                    ],
                    [
                        106.817351,
                        -6.201177
                    ],
                    [
                        106.852353,
                        -6.201177
                    ],
                    [
                        106.852353,
                        -6.24152
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "attributes": {}
    },
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "quote_count": 0,
    "reply_count": 0,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "urls": [],
        "user_mentions": [
            {
                "screen_name": "irfanzayo",
                "name": "irfan zayanto",
                "id": 60049976,
                "id_str": "60049976",
                "indices": [
                    0,
                    10
                ]
            },
            {
                "screen_name": "puisisi",
                "name": "Puisi Pancara",
                "id": 32809069,
                "id_str": "32809069",
                "indices": [
                    11,
                    19
                ]
            },
            {
                "screen_name": "tasyak",
                "name": "Tasya Kurnia",
                "id": 41986880,
                "id_str": "41986880",
                "indices": [
                    20,
                    27
                ]
            }
        ],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "in",
    "timestamp_ms": "1507710981481"
}
```

Another error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\fase
>   1-20170930T062552Z-001\transformCSV.py", line 7, in 
>       tweet = json.loads(line)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json__init__.py",
>   line 354, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py",
>   line 339, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py",
>   line 357, in raw_decode
>       raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char
>   1)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tanabata\Desktop\Putang ina mo\spli.py", line 8, in <module>
    tweet = json.load(fo)
  File "C:\Users\Tanabata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Tanabata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Tanabata\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 2893)
```

[Json file itself](http://www.mediafire.com/file/l3rzzbe0nbu1nlu/Sclass.json)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `csv`. You have to create a `writer`:

```
import json
import csv

with open('Sclass.json', 'r') as fo, open('Hasil_Tweets.csv', 'a') as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for line in fo:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        writer.writerow([tweet['id'],tweet['timestamp_ms'],tweet['user']['name'],
            tweet['user']['statuses_count'],tweet['user']['friends_count'],
            tweet['user']['followers_count'],
            tweet['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates'],tweet['text']])
```

For your second question, it seems, you don't have a json-lines-file but a file with a single json dataset. So reading line by line is wrong, you should read the file as a whole:

```
with open('Sclass.json', 'r') as fo:
    tweet = json.load(fo)

with open('Hasil_Tweets.csv', 'a') as fw
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    writer.writerow([tweet['id'],tweet['timestamp_ms'],tweet['user']['name'],
        tweet['user']['statuses_count'],tweet['user']['friends_count'],
        tweet['user']['followers_count'],
        tweet['place']['bounding_box']['coordinates'],tweet['text']])
```

Comment: thank you sir, but i got an other erorr: AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: thank you sir, but an other erorr : writerow() takes exactly one argument (8 given) sry bother you sir.

Comment: Sorry, you need to call `writerow` with a list.

Comment: how do i call it with a list sir ?

Comment: by creating a list. Look at my answer.

Comment: thanks, it's work but after first line they strop printing and give an give error.  the error is : Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\fase 1-20170930T062552Z-001\transformCSV.py", line 7 the rest of the error is in the top page becasue i can't write it all here sry.

Comment: `Sclass.json` does not contain valid json.

Comment: i have tried with other json file and the result still the same the when i print the json file it appear the first line only. shoud i made 'writer.writerow' as a loop? but there is a loop already in for line  in fo.

Comment: @Tanabata: answer extended.

Comment: i already try with the second code. the result is :   raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 2893) the full error the the question

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you are working with tables (csv being one) think pandas (my opinion).

In this case we can use pandas json_normalize to interpret your json file.

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

with open("Sclass.json.json") as f:
    df = json_normalize(json.load(f))

cols = ["id","timestamp_ms","user.name",
        "user.statuses_count","user.friends_count","user.followers_count",
        "place.bounding_box.coordinates","text"]

df[cols].to_csv("Hasil_Tweets.csv",sep=",",index=False) # outputs to csv
```

---

Pandas come with many output options, one of them being a html table. I will use this to show the outut:

```
print(df[cols].to_html(index=False)) # outputs to html to show result
```

Output

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>id</th>
      <th>timestamp_ms</th>
      <th>user.name</th>
      <th>user.statuses_count</th>
      <th>user.friends_count</th>
      <th>user.followers_count</th>
      <th>place.bounding_box.coordinates</th>
      <th>text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>918032510927355904</td>
      <td>1507710981481</td>
      <td>Mutiara Sisyanni D</td>
      <td>6507</td>
      <td>237</td>
      <td>354</td>
      <td>[[[106.817351, -6.24152], [106.817351, -6.2011...</td>
      <td>@irfanzayo @puisisi @tasyak Lo tuh kebiasaan o...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you sir. but i get some problem here,1.raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) 2.json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 2893) whats wrong with it ? when you able to extract the data and iam not >.<

Comment: @Tanabata Hmm.. I took the text you posted and created a json file with same name. Do you have more data possibly? I normally use jsonlint.com to verify if something is wrong.

Comment: thank you sir i have try to validate the json and the result is many tings not right and i try an other json file from = https://nocodewebscraping.com/twitter-json-examples/                            witch has json file aswell and they give quite same error :     raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 89 column 2 (char 3438) the online different is line, collumn and chart. ohh i post my json file on the question above. thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as another answer.

The *.json you shared is actually a big file containing multiple json strings but just every two rows. How you got this file from the beginning I don't know but you can read it in using this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("Sclass.json") as f:
    data = [json.loads(row.strip()) for row in f.readlines()[0::2]]
```

However, when reading this structure to a dataframe you can see that it really isn't any clear structure:

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Conclusion: Your issue is something else entirely.

Comment: thank you sir. so the json file not well structured sir ? well if you don't mind can you correct my streamlistener so  that i can get proper json file or csv file this is my conde:                                                                      def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('tescsv.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True
 
    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True